# How to insert package dirtytalk in Texmaker

Tags: packages, miktex

I am trying to insert in TexMaker the package dirtytalk but I haven't been successful till now. I also have MikTex but is not available there in the list of packages available. Morever, I tried to manually upload it as a directory but I get an error by MikTex because the folder is not a tds ... ?
I looked at the documentation on how to create such directory file but I can't make it through. 
Can someone help me? Is there a fast way to do it?

Comment: Packages has nothing to do with texmaker, you need to install it in miktex, before you try to install it manually  see if it is available in the miktex package manager (I've never heard of this package before). Installing by hand is not for the faint hearted

Answer (score 2):

It's just a simple one-file package so you can just use it in the same directory as your document.

Copy `dirtytalk.ins` and `dirtytalk.dtx` from

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dirtytalk

into the folder with your document and then run  process `dirtytalk.ins` with tex  this will generate `dirtytalk.sty` in that folder, you can then process your document using

```
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
```

as usual.

Comment: it gave me the following error when I try to run it on TexMaker: Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1-interaction=nonstopmode%.tex

Do you know what is the problem?